# How to modify the "Elevens" card game to fit a different set of criteria?

Tags: java

I coded a simple version of the "Elevens" card game, and would like to make some modifications with the following criteria:

1. You can use as many cards as you want to add up to 11.
2. Cards with the clubs and spades suits are worth negative values.

Here's the code I've got for the regular Elevens game - it checks for an 11-pair in a list of selected cards:

```
private boolean containsPairSum11(List<Integer> selectedCards)
{
    for (int sk1 = 0; sk1 < selectedCards.size(); sk1++)
    {
        int k1 = selectedCards.get(sk1).intValue();

        for (int sk2 = sk1 + 1; sk2 < selectedCards.size(); sk2++)
        {
            int k2 = selectedCards.get(sk2).intValue();

            if (cardsAt(k1).pointValue() + cardsAt(k2).pointValue() == 11)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The list *selectedCards* contains all of the indexes of the selected cards, so that they can be passed into the method *cardsAt()* which will return the respective Card object. I'm really having trouble figuring out the algorithm for achieving the above mentioned criteria, and I would really appreciate any help on the issue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't accounted at all for suits yet. Here's a potential model:

```
public enum Suit {
    CLUBS, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES;

    public int getCardValue(int face) {
        switch (this) {
            case CLUBS:
            case SPADES:
                return -face;
            case HEARTS:
            case DIAMONDS:
                return +face;
        }
    }
}

public class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final int face;

    public int getValue() {
        return suit.getCardValue(face);
    }
}

public class Hand {
    private final List<Card> cards;

    public Stream<List<Card>> getCombinationsThatEqualTotal(int total) {
        return streamCombinations()
            .filter(c -> matchesTotal(c, total));
    }

    private Stream<List<Card>> streamCombinations() {
        ...
    }

    private boolean matchesTotal(List<Card> cards, int total) {
        return cards.stream().mapToInt(Card::getValue).sum() == total;
    }
}
```

I haven't done the work of generating the combinations because you asked about an algorithm to satisfy the criteria. There are good answers on SO about efficient ways of generating all combinations from a list.

The advantage of your combo generation returning a stream is that you can then further filter, sort etc. For example, to get the largest combination that satisfies the criteria:

```
List<Card> largestCombo = hand.getCombinationsThatEqualTotal(11)
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
    .orElse(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
```